# Enums and Singletons

Tags: java, enums, singleton

Consider the following implementation

```
public enum Singleton {

    INSTANCE;
    private final OnlyOne onlyOne;

    Singleton() {
        onlyOne = new OnlyOne();
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Singleton one = getInstance();
        one.onlyOne.method();
    }

}

class OnlyOne {

    public void method() {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Here I have tried to implement the Singleton using `enum`. I want `OnlyOne` to have just one instance. My question is how do I restrict clients from instantiating objects of class `OnlyOne`? Because in some other class we can easily do this

```
OnlyOne  one = new OnlyOne();
```

I cannot provide a private constructor for it because doing so will break this

```
Singleton() {
  onlyOne = new OnlyOne();
}
```

Do I need to use the enum as an inner member of `OnlyOne` class ? Any suggestions?

Comment: since your main concern is that you dont want to create more than one instance you can make class `onlyOne` as singleton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

INSTANCE itself is the singleton. Add your method directly to the enum.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Singleton.INSTANCE.method();
}

public enum Singleton {
    INSTANCE;
    public void method() {
        System.out.println(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: oh yes! I did not realise it :-) What I am trying to achieve is quite unrelated.